# finding the highest total for a consecutive group of entries in a column - EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas

rather then finding the highest single entry, i want the highest total for a consecutive group of n entries e.g within a column of 100 values i want to look to find 10 consecutive cells whose sum is a maximum

I say 10 as an example i wish to be able to change that easily.

Comment: Do you want the maximum sum **value** or the **location** of the consecutive cells??

Comment: This is a very tough task for a formula. Are you open to User Defined Function solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the cleanest way to do this is with a User Defined Function (UDF).

Here is a small routine that will do it. Place this routine in a standard code module:

```
Function MaxN(n&, r As Range)
    Dim i&, j&, m#, t#, v
    v = r.Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If UBound(v) - i + 1 >= n Then
            t = 0
            For j = i To i + n - 1
                t = t + v(j, 1)
            Next
            If t > m Then m = t
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MaxN = m
End Function
```

Then on the worksheet where you want to calculate the max, pick a cell where you'd like to have the calculation return and enter this formula:

```
=MaxN(10,A1:A100)
```

That's it.

With this UDF you can easily change the '10' to whatever you like and you can easily adjust the vertical range location and size by altering the formula.

Comment: This is great exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** through **A100**, in **B10** enter:

```
=SUM(A1:A10)
```

and copy down through **B100**

Then in another cell, use:

```
=MAX(B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array formula version (should be confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`)

```
=MAX(A1:A100+A2:A101+A3:A102+A4:A103+A5:A104+A6:A105+A7:A106+A8:A107+A9:A108+A10:A109)
```

(probably not the easiest one to maintain in future).