# How do I find the largest contiguous n length range within a larger range

Tags: excel, vba, max, user-defined-functions

I am trying to find the cell references for the largest n length contiguous subset of values in my range.

A similar question has been posted before, ( [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635438/finding-the-highest-total-for-a-consecutive-group-of-entries-in-a-column-excel/) ) however it only returned the sum of the subset, how would I find the specific cell references?

For example, if n = 3, the largest subset range would be A3:A5

```
Cell    Value
A1  2
A2  5
A3  8
A4  2
A5  9
A6  7
A7  2
A8  9
A9  5
A10 3
```

Below is the code by Excel Hero from the shared link above which returns the sum of the subset

```
Function MaxN(n&, r As Range)
    Dim i&, j&, m#, t#, v
    v = r.Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If UBound(v) - i + 1 >= n Then
            t = 0
            For j = i To i + n - 1
                t = t + v(j, 1)
            Next
            If t > m Then m = t
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MaxN = m
End Function
```

Comment: You want Range of that Subset rather than the Sum ?

Comment: Make the if branch `If t > m Then` : `m = t`  :  `MaxN = r(i, 1).Row` : `End If` . MaxN wo\ill give you first row of the range. remove MaxN before `End function`

Comment: Better, use the Below answer, that will print the range it is.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAU it worked like a charm

Comment: @ Bobby Heyer Welcome, You made my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
Function MaxN(n&, r As Range)
    Dim i&, j&, m#, t#, v, str
    v = r.Value2


    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If UBound(v) - i + 1 >= n Then
            t = 0
            For j = i To i + n - 1
                t = t + v(j, 1)
            Next
            If t > m Then
            m = t
            str = i
            End If
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 MaxN = Range(Cells(str, r.Column), Cells(str + n, r.Column)).Address
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Mikku It works perfectly. really appreciate it